# Sublime Text Shortcut for Selecting all similarly indented lines

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I came across a [website](http://blog.generalassemb.ly/sublime-text-3-tips-tricks-shortcuts/) that said that CTRL/⌘-SHIFT-J selects all similarly indented text in sublime; however this does not seem to be the case in the actual doc which says:

`Added Expand Selection to Indentation (Command+Shift+J on OS X, and Ctrl+Shift+J on Windows and Linux)`

Does anyone know the shortcut for this action? This would be really useful to me!

Comment: umm... how is the website you linked different from the docs? They both say exactly the same thing.

Comment: I guess I thought "expand selection to indentation" didn't mean "select all similar indented lines"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open your default key bindings (Preferences > Key Bindings - Default) you can search for `"command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "indentation"}` to see your set key binding.

The full thing looks like this in Linux:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+j"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "indentation"} }
```

Comment: Ahh, I don't know why it wasn't working. But thanks for pointing me to this! I totally forgot I could just rebind it in keybindings...